# UIPageControl design challenge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

My app has a UITabBarController that loads many different UINavigationControllers. I want a UIPageControl to switch between the different UINavigationControllers. Do I place the UIPageControl in my UINavigationController or in my appDelegate? Suggestions and best practices are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a relative noob, but I believe the UIPageControl is just an element that you send messages to to visually display to users what page they're on within a set of pages.  My understanding is that UIPageControl is *not* a "controller", but just a visual queue element.  Thus, I believe it belongs near the view element that's being paged through by the user.

I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, UIPageControl is a control, not a controller. If you're doing switching, you'll need to do the "controller" bit on your own. Not sure how the tab bar controller plays in to this.